# Best method to pass Array values or store and use them among many classes

Tags: java

I plan to create a simple User Login in java using Arrays to store user and pass (despite I know its not the right way, its just a test). I was wondering how it is possible to keep array values among different classes. 
example: I have Main class which array is defined in, Register class which gives value to the array in Main class and Login class which access the array in Main class. But when I create an object of main class to access the array in Login class, values will be reseted. What should I do in order to keep the array values once I create an instance of the class which my array placed in? 
any suggestion?

Comment: Do not edit people's answers in the way you attempted to do with BVSmallman's answer. That isn't what editing is for. You should have posted your edit as a comment.

Comment: I hate stackOverflow Its general rules makes it easy for selfish people to rate down any question might be asked by a novice. despite I follow the rules and search for my answer for hours then I post the question. Correct maybe I asked in a bad way because English is not my native language but in the other hand I did show what I meant by this question.

Comment: There is nothing selfish about down-voting. It actually costs the down-voter reputation, so they're actually self-*sacrificing* by down-voting your question. The problem isn't with down-voters, it's with your question. It's impossible to figure out what you're asking and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Concur, I revised the question, hope it makes it possible to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have many problems and questions with this, but purely to answer your question...If you want a variable to be accessible independent of the instance of the object, use the static keyword.

Comment: your short answer didn't help at all.

Comment: You ask: " What should I do in order to keep the array values once I create an instance of the class which my array placed in?"  My answer remains the same, if you have values which are independent of a specific instance of a class, but yet still appropriately placed in that class, use the static keyword.

Comment: When you ask vague code-less questions, you will almost always get vague code-less answers.  Put effort into your questions, ask very specific questions, and provide complete examples of code and I'm certain you will be happier with the responses you receive.